# html value=" " not displaying

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

```
<div id="minus_vacancies">
        <h4>Mínimo de vagas</h4>
        <div>
          <input type="button" id="decrease_btn" name="decrease_btn" value="-" onclick="subtractVacancies(this)">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="vacancies_qtt" type="text" name="vacancies_qtt" value="0" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="button" id="increase_btn" name="increase_btn" value="+" onclick="addVacancies(this)">
        </div>
</div>
```

Hey! I am making a Decrement/Increment buttons with the value on the middle. The buttons work fine but I can´t see the number. Its not displaying the value="0" of the vacancies_qtt

Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! Please provide the code for the addVacancies() and subtractVacancies() functions.

Comment: Can you please add your `subtractVacancies` and `addVacancies` code? Also, what is the purpose of the double replace in the `oninput`?

Comment: It works for me. See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fhxg4752/

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for `addVacancies()` and `subtractVacancies()`:

```
function addVacancies(){
  let num = document.getElementById("vacancies_qtt");
  num.value++;
}

function subtractVacancies(){
  let num = document.getElementById("vacancies_qtt");
  num.value--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function addVacancies() {
    cur = parseInt($("#vacancies_qtt").val())+1;
    $("#vacancies_qtt").val(cur);
  }

 function subtractVacancies() {
    cur = parseInt($("#vacancies_qtt").val())-1;
    $("#vacancies_qtt").val(cur);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minus_vacancies">
    <h4>Mínimo de vagas</h4>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="decrease_btn" name="decrease_btn" value="-" onclick="subtractVacancies(this)">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="vacancies_qtt" type="text" name="vacancies_qtt" value="0" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="increase_btn" name="increase_btn" value="+" onclick="addVacancies(this)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this out